# Codeigniter htaccess and configuration when uploading website to server

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, server, config

I have a server and I made a website using Codeigniter. I used the wamp server to do my project. now I want to upload it to the server I have so I need to change the configurations and the htaccess file. but I don't know what to edit in these files.

autoload:
I have changed nothing in this file only

`$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','array' , 'date');`

config:

`$config['base_url']    = 'http://www.example.com/';
$config['uri_protocol']    = 'AUTO';`

database:

`$db['default']['hostname'] = 'http://www.example.com';`

route:

`$route['(:any)'] = 'my_controller/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = "my_controller";
$route['404_override'] = '';`

this is what I have changed in all the configuration files

Comment: You have to edit your question and provide code for files you think should be modified.

Comment: `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'http://www.example.com';` should be either `$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';` either `$db['default']['hostname'] = '1.2.3.4';//ip address of server where db is`.

Comment: Glad to know. Enjoy your coding. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server requires some times a different htacess

I have found a link with lots of different htaccess main directory examples https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

This might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step by step tutorial to upload codeigniter app in server. follow the following link. This really helped me.
[Step By Step guide to Install Codeigniter Website in Server](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/how-to-install-and-use-codeigniter-on-your-server/)