# Model file not returning values in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

My model file working on localhost but when I upload, it returns null values. Please explain to me how `database.php` is wrong.

My `database.php`:

```
$active_group = 'default';

$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'http://niation.com';

$db['default']['username'] = 'nire';

$db['default']['password'] = 'xxxxu23';

$db['default']['database'] = 'trrtuu';

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql'

$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';

$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;

$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

My model file:

```
<?php

class Play extends CI_Model
{

    function getdata()
    {
        $data = $this->db->select('info')->get('home');

         return $data->result();

    }
```

My controller file

```
class Nirmal extends CI_Controller {
public function about()
{
    $this->load->model('play');
    $data['info']=$this->play->getdata();
    $this->load->view('main1',$data);
}
```

My view file

```
<?php foreach ($info as $item):?>
<p><?php echo $item->info;?></p>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: I think it is similar issue to this one with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29904621/codeigniter-htaccess-and-configuration-when-uploading-website-to-server#comment-48054596) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your hostname is wrong, by default mysql connections are not through HTTP.

Check if you can connect to the database from your machine locally, [check this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8107449/connecting-to-a-remote-database-through-codeigniter) which may help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'http://niation.com';

change this to 
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';

and then try to run

Comment: ya i tried in both cases even i put ip address also .but it didn't fetch any data from database

Answer (score 0):

simply update your default hostname.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
```

and then upload it to server,Then run website.

Comment: ya i tried in both cases even i put ip address also .but it didn't fetch any data from database